# ACM2012-900-2P filter can be used on USB 3.0 lines of a Type-C connector?

Tags: usb, filter, emc, emi-filtering, usb-c

I have doubts that this CMF is recommended for USB3.0 due to his bandwidth. I am afraid it will filter the USB signal. Can someone explain better the SCCC21 and SDS21 characteristics from here? https://product.tdk.com/en/search/emc/emc/cmf_cmc/info?part_no=ACM2012-900-2P-T002

Comment: Recommended by who?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several misconceptions in application of EMI/ESD inductors in USB area (or other high-speed differential signaling environment). The ACM2012-900-2P is a two-line common-mode (CM) choke. Purpose of common-mode chokes is to attenuate COMMON noise/interference. So all CM chokes are rated for "common-mode impedance", and rarely specify their DIFFERENTIAL mode impedance.

There are two aspects of the problem: differential loss, and differential impedance.

The issue is that USB signal quality strongly depends on uniformity of DIFFERENTIAL impedance along the transmission line. Unfortunately, the nature of inductance of coils is such that the differential impedance just can't be independent of frequency. I couldn't find a simple impedance chart for ACM choke, so here are characteristics of one typical CM choke offered by Murata for USB3 applications:

[image]

This one is actually suitable for USB3, more or less. The spectrum of USB3 signal in active mode spans something like from 1 GHz to 3-4 GHz, with Nyquist frequency of 2.5 GHz. I marked this range in the picture above. As one can see, the DIFFERENTIAL impedance of this choke varies from 40 Ohms to 200 Ohms in the working range of USB3 signal. Insertion of such a horrible impedance mismatched device into 90-Ohm transmission line causes substantial distortions/reflection that are not accounted into USB 3.0 channel model, and therefore receivers are having difficulty to compensate for "unknowns".

The second issue is the frequency-dependent loss along the choke. The Sdd21 is the differential loss across the choke. ACM2012 chart shows about 6 dB loss at 2.5 Ghz. This effect is actually less harmful for signal quality, since it kind-of follows the standard channel model of USB3, and therefore can be compensated by CTLE tuning during link training phase. However, the loss of 6dB@2.5Ghz constitutes a nearly "longest" channel, so the choke will "eat" all cable allowances, and the device will likely work only with short USB cables.

In short, common-mode chokes introduce horrible imperfections into channel transmission lines, and should be used only as a last resort, when operating in really harsh environment using a really weak USB 3.0 silicon.